# Null Handling in confluent KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

Could you please let me know how to handle Null value in KSQL . I tried to handle 4 possible ways but not being resolved. Tried with 4 Ways to Replace NULL with a different Value in KSQL but giving the issue.

```
ksql> select PORTFOLIO_PLAN_ID from topic_stream_name; null

ksql> select COALESCE(PORTFOLIO_PLAN_ID,'N/A') from topic_stream_name; Can't find any functions with the name 'COALESCE' 
ksql> select IFNULL(PORTFOLIO_PLAN_ID,'N/A') from topic_stream_name; Function 'IFNULL' does not accept parameters of types:[BIGINT, VARCHAR(STRING)] 
ksql> select if(PORTFOLIO_PLAN_ID IS NOT NULL,PORTFOLIO_PLAN_ID,'N/A') FROM topic_stream_name; Can't find any functions with the name 'IF'
```

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @cricket_007 references, there is an [open ticket](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1181) for handling NULL values in this way in KSQL.

One workaround you could use is using INSERT INTO. It's not very elegant, and certainly not as flexible as a function such as `COALESCE`:

```
# Set up some sample data, run this from bash
# For more info about kafkacat see
#    https://docs.confluent.io/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html
    kafkacat -b kafka-broker:9092 \
            -t topic_with_nulls \
            -P <<EOF
{"col1":1,"col2":16000,"col3":"foo"}
{"col1":2,"col2":42000}
{"col1":3,"col2":94000,"col3":"bar"}
{"col1":4,"col2":12345}
EOF
```

Here's the KSQL workaround for handling NULLs in `col3`:

```
-- Register the topic
CREATE STREAM topic_with_nulls (COL1 INT, COL2 INT, COL3 VARCHAR) \
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='topic_with_nulls',VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');

-- Query the topic to show there are some null values
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';
Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' from 'null' to 'earliest'
ksql> SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM topic_with_nulls;
1 | 16000 | foo
2 | 42000 | null
3 | 94000 | bar
4 | 12345 | null

-- Create a derived stream, with just records with no NULLs in COL3
CREATE STREAM NULL_WORKAROUND AS \
  SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM topic_with_nulls WHERE COL3 IS NOT NULL;

-- Insert into the derived stream any records where COL3 *is* NULL, replacing it with a fixed string
INSERT INTO NULL_WORKAROUND \
  SELECT COL1, COL2, 'N/A' AS COL3 FROM topic_with_nulls WHERE COL3 IS NULL;

-- Confirm that the NULL substitution worked
ksql> SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM NULL_WORKAROUND;
1 | 16000 | foo
2 | 42000 | N/A
3 | 94000 | bar
4 | 12345 | N/A
```